UI delay when using PinLayout .all() with UIImageView
I'm using PinLayout to set background image on my view
final class MDetailView: UIView {
    let backgroundImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName:  "background"))
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        return imageView
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupSubviews()
    }

    private func setupSubviews() {
        addSubview(backgroundImageView)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        configureSubviews()
    }

    private func configureSubviews() {
        backgroundImageView.pin
            .all()
    }
}

The background is delayed for a second before closing and then closes completely. I need to remove delay
I removed backgroundImageView.pin.all() and change it to backgroundColor = .gray - it helped to remove delay, but I need to set image for background

let backgroundImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName:  "background"))
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    return imageView
}()

Adding imageView.clipsToBounds = true resolved problem
